# implement Symbol Table and DFS

Tags: testing, compiler-construction, execution, verification, model-driven-development

I want to implement `symbolic execution engine` for a language. I need to store type, value, etc. of variables in `Symbol Table`. I have global and local variables in for statements and operations.

if I don't have local variables it seems such this Sequence also appropriate:

```
Sequence {Map{name->'a', value <- 'A', type <- 'Member'}, Map {name->'b', value <- 'B', type <- 'Family'},...}
```

but in general and local scopes, I don't have an idea.

Also, I want to do `Depth First Search (DFS)` in a graph of program instructions. I wanna to fork execution in conditional statements and consider both true and false paths.

I want to know with which structure should I create such a `Symbol Table` and `DFS`.

e.g., Does `Stack` is a good structure for DFS?

**Edit:** I implement Symbol Table with Stack. However, for the DFS part I find `stack` as a good structure. but yet I have no idea about the implementing such DFS.

Comment: @Ira Baxter would you please help me about the DFS part?